# Update content without the user having to refresh their page

Tags: plugins

I'm running a video streaming site of a sports feed. I would like to have a sidebar of live scores that we updated as they come in. Of course I'm only looking to have the sidebar update, and not the entire page as that would disturb the video.

It's a bit like having a football score update.

Any ideas?

Cheers

Dom

Comment: How often will the sidebar change?

Comment: What source will you be using for the scores?

Comment: You'd need to ping the site at regular intervals to fetch new data for your sidebar with javascript ( ajax/rest ), but right now there's so little information in your question it's not possible to talk about it in anything other than the most generic terms. E.g. you need a source to fetch the football score updates from, for which I'd recommend building a REST API endpoint, but there's no information about how these scores are stored or where they're coming from, and no code for your static version of the scores